# How and what test to apply in this Event study?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I'm currently grappling with a particular issue. I conducted an event study focused on the M&A activities of major tech companies. For the analysis, I employed an observation period spanning 255 days leading up to the event window. The event window, in turn, comprises three distinct values:

1. CAR PRE EVENT: The cumulative abnormal returns (CAR) five days prior to the event.
2. CAR EVENT: The abnormal return (AR) on the actual event day.
3. CAR POST EVENT: The cumulative abnormal returns (CAR) five days following the event.

To compute the AR for each day, I utilized the Market Model, and the determination of Alpha and Beta involved a linear regression of the log returns of the S&P500  against those of the  firm.

It's worth noting that each firm in the study has its own set of events.

My current challenge lies in identifying the appropriate test and the specific values to employ. I'm struggling to ascertain the standard deviation, the relevant samples, and other crucial parameters. If you require additional details to provide guidance, please feel free to ask.

I appreciate your assistance in advance!

Comment: What are your hypotheses?